# Day organising app

Tags: software-recommendation, calendar, productivity

I am looking a sort of a day organiser for my Ubuntu laptop with Google calendar integration and preferably cross-platform so I could use it on my Android phone. Basically I need a to-do-list with an option to track the progress, a nice visualisation of the day, ability to see my Google calendar events and appointments. I wonder if anything like this exists. Any recommendations are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

#### GNOME Evolution

From my personal experience I can recommend [*GNOME Evolution*](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evolution/). You can install it as usual:

```
sudo apt-get install evolution evolution-plugins
```

It has *Mail*, *Contacts*, *Calendar*, *Tasks* and *Memos*.

*Calendar* works normally with *Google Calendar*. Not sure about *Tasks*.

#### KOrganizer

[KOrganizer](https://userbase.kde.org/KOrganizer) from KDE may help too. I did not tried it.

```
sudo apt-get install korganizer
```

#### GNOME Calendar

If you need only calendar you can start with [*GNOME Calendar*](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Calendar):

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-calendar
```

#### Emacs OrgMode

You can try [OrgMode](https://orgmode.org/) as productivity platform too. But it is terminal based.